# Detect if key is down mac python

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7

I've googled all over the place.

I have a python application and I'd like to detect if a key is down (on OSX).

The only answers I've been able to find are either libraries for windows, or libraries that require an application window to be active (like pygame).

Similar to how pymouse has a position() method.

I'd like to be able to do something in my code like:

```
if keyboard.keydown(<key code>):
  # do something
elif keyboard.keycode(<some other keycode>):
  # do something
```

On Mac.

Comment: More than 2k and no code? Additionally, why would you want to detect if a key was pressed if not in an interactive environment (which needs additional libraries)?

Comment: I built an app that takes screenshots of the users screen and performs actions in the background and then interacts with the screen again. i'd like to be able to allow the user to adjust the speed of certain parts of the application using up and down keys. it is not an application with a GUI

Comment: You mean a specific key or a key in general ???

Comment: In general. So imagine using pymouse.position() you get the position of the mouse no matter what application has focus. i'm asking how to do with with keyboard. something like keyboard.keydown(<some key code>)

Comment: @SiHa i saw that post, but it dealt with windows python not mac

Comment: OK, Missed the 'mac' in the title. You should add it to the question as it's easily missed.

Comment: @SiHa That doesn't look like python...

Comment: I'll get my coat. Sorry,  been a long day.

Comment: [This code](https://github.com/syndbg/python-keylogger/blob/master/keylogger/platforms/osx.py) looks like it might work for you.

Answer (score 5):

The only way I could think of is [tty](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tty.html) or [termios](https://docs.python.org/2/library/termios.html#module-termios).

Here is a minimal example that waits for user input and prints the keycode if 'a' pressed ...

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python

    import sys,tty
    tty.setcbreak(sys.stdin)  
    key = ord(sys.stdin.read(1))  # key captures the key-code 
    # based on the input we do something - in this case print something
    if key==97:
        print "you pressed a"
    else:
        print "you pressed something else ..."  
    sys.exit(0)
```

Hope it helps!

**Note:** This solution refers to linux/mac operating systems specifically - for windows there are other ways!

Answer (score 0):

Python comex with tkinter, a gui framework that includes cross-platform key press and release handling.  The gui part can be suppressed if one only wants the event handling.  This works as expected on my Windows machine.  It should work on your Mac.

```
from time import sleep
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()  # Do not show root window.
spacedown = False
def press_s(dummy):
    global spacedown
    spacedown = True
    print('down')
def release_s(dummy):
    global spacedown
    spacedown = False
    print('up')
root.bind('<KeyPress- >', press_s)
root.bind('<KeyRelease- >', release_s)
while True:
    sleep(1)
    root.update()
    print('tick', 'down' if spacedown else 'up')
```

In the bind statements, replace the space  after the `-` with the key (such as `a` or `*`) or a [keyname](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/key-names.html).  Whenever you want to detect the current state of the key, call root.update to process queued events and set keydown.

Answer (score -3):

You could use the input command
awesome = input("how awesome are you")

although this requires the user to press enter

then you could do something like this 
print(awesome)